# Discover what email is linked to a Salesforce username?

Tags: login, username

Short question: How can I figure out what email is linked to a specific username?

Long question: A new employee just joined. He signed up for a trial Salesforce account using his company email (dan@company.com) as the username. So when I made him his official company SF user I had to use something that was not his actual work email (dan2@company.com)

Salesforces has their confusing email needs to be separate from username policy (which has to be in email format?) So, this is going to confuse my new employee.

It should be simple to change his trial username to something else then change his company username to his company email. However, he can't remember his password. No problem, we tried to reset it, but never got the reset email. Checked the spam folder. Checked his personal email, and personal spam folder. Nothing.

**So is there a way to figure out what email is actually linked to a username?** I have my doubts because that is exactly what someone looking to steal an account would need to know, but I figured I would ask.

Comment: There is actually a good reason to have username and emails separate - usernames are globally unique throughout the SFDC universe whereas emails, of course, can be reused across many usernames. In large, multi SFDC orgs, I've seen by convention, usernames suffixed by xxx where `xxx` depends on which org the user is being created in

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't discover the email for a given username from salesforce.com through normal means without being able to log in.

Longer answer: Support won't give you this information without you proving that you are who you say you are (and that's usually not easy, especially for a trial). They may decide to *verify* what the email address is, however, if you give them a list of possibilities. However, assuming the user account was a trial, and that trial has expired, you can simply ask that support change the now defunct user name to something else so you can reclaim the user name; as long as the user is inactive or the trial has expired, they will usually accommodate you.

If, however, it was a developer account, it will never expire, and you will never be able to reclaim the account unless you can determine which email address was used. It's not normally possible to recover a developer edition account if you ever lose access to it. You'll have to deal with the "wrong" username unless/until your employee figures out what the email address was.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the user originally signed up with his work email address - otherwise why would he use his work email as the username but a different email for his email address?

So, if your user never received the password reset then there's a chance the trial org has expired and is now locked.  Locked orgs are automatically deleted after 30 days (I think) after which you will be able to recycle his user name.

Support would be able to confirm that, but as per previous answers they'll be reluctant to do so without appropriate identification.  But if my assumption holds true (and he did use his company email address) then I imagine they'll accept that as proof of identity?

Comment: In case this isn't related to his trial org - could your user already exist in your org - eg through a community account, chatter free, or chatter external?